# Laravel 5 - Get newly inserted id in transaction?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I am running a transaction that should create a user, and fire off an event to do additional things with the new user id, including creating a settings table where the foreign key user_id in the settings table is the newly created user_id (providing the transaction works of course).

Here is what I have so far:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    DB::table('users')->insert([
              'email' => $email,
              'password' => $password
    ]);

    event(new UserWasStored($newUserId)); // How do I get the $newUserId?
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
}

DB::commit();
```

How can I get the `$newUserId` passed to the event within the transaction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts)  you should be using the `insertGetId` method

```
$newUserId= DB::table('users')->insertGetId([
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your `User` model to create a new user. In return, it'll give you the user object to work with.

```
$user = User::create([
    'email'     => 'john@example.com',
    'password'  => bcrypt('your-password')
]);

dd($user->id);
```

Comment: As of Laravel 5.5 this *does not* work inside an uncommitted transaction. The id field is always `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = DB::table('table')->insert( $data )->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: hey stefan, to format the code on a single line, wrap it with the back ticks `

Comment: Throws: `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Call to a member function lastInsertId() on boolean` because insert() returns true/false.